# API calls only works with IP Address, not with my Domain (Node.js Express, Godaddy, Google Compute Engine)

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, postman

I have a node server running on google cloud Compute engine.
i am using ubuntu as my os on Compute engine.

i added firewall rules as 0.0.0.0/0 tcp:4000
my external ip is 35.196.xxx.xxx.
and my node server running on port 4000, so i mapped  35.196.xxx.xxx:4000 with my godaddy domain

i wrote some APIs on my server and i can access that api (POST) using post man with my 
**External IP**

i am **able to access** my website **with my domain**. but i **cant** access my **api using my domain**.

ie;

> http://35.196.xxx.xxx:4000/lyriclines/get-songs-by-person
>   which is ok
>
> http://mydomain. com/lyriclines/get-songs-by-person
>   which is NOT OK

i am getting this error while using domain,

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>mydomain.com </title>
        <META name="description" content="None">
        <META name="keywords" content="None">

    </head>
    <frameset rows="100%,*" border="0">
        <frame src="http://35.196.xxx.xxx:4000/lyriclines/get-songs-by-person" frameborder="0" />
        <frame frameborder="0" noresize />
    </frameset>
    <!-- pageok -->
    <!-- 08 -->
    <!-- -->

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep the port 80 firewall rule open to 0.0.0.0 and remove the one for 4000.  Then setup an nginx proxy that listens on 80 to route web requests to your web server port and api requests to your api port. [Use this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37647978/7929314) as a reference.

Comment: now I am able to get that woking. but went to another problem. hope you can answer this. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59332542/nodejs-with-nginx-csrf-verification-failed-request-aborted